# Can dplyr access a POSTGRES 9.3.5 VIEW?

Tags: r, postgresql, dplyr

My R (v. 3.1.1) dplyr (v. 0.3.0.2) can access my POSTGRES 9.3.5 TABLE, but not my VIEW in same database.

Does dplyr support access a POSTGRES 9.3.5 VIEW?

In POSTGRES my VIEW is defined like this:

```
centralstats=# \d "nicStats5"
           View "public.nicStats5"
    Column    |       Type        | Modifiers
--------------+-------------------+-----------
 affectedId   | integer           |
 timeRecorded | bigint            |
 dn           | character varying |
 bytesRx      | bigint            |
```

View definition:

```
 SELECT "adaptorNICVnicStats"."affectedId",
    "adaptorNICVnicStats"."timeRecorded",
    "affectedId2Dn".dn,
    "adaptorNICVnicStats"."bytesRx"
   FROM "adaptorNICVnicStats",
    "affectedId2Dn"
  WHERE "adaptorNICVnicStats"."affectedId" = "affectedId2Dn"."affectedId";
```

IN R All the databases, which my VIEW is defined upon, can be accessed from dplyr. 
And the access to my VIEW fails as shown below:

```
centralstats <- src_postgres("centralstats",host = NULL, port = NULL,"postgres","Jmu2014!")
adaptorNICVnicStats <-tbl(centralstats, "adaptorNICVnicStats")
affectedId2Dn <-tbl(centralstats, "affectedId2Dn")
nicStats5 <-tbl(centralstats, "nicStats5")
## Fejl: Table nicStats5 not found in database  //* COMMENT: "Fejl" is the Danish word for ERROR
```

Comment: I haven't tried using `VIEW`s, but take a look at the info on [creating a dplyr SQL backend](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/new-sql-backend.html). It definitely is `TABLE` oriented, but the [SQLite backend](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/353825f7825916e904b5dabbe3b6e6df8c4d6fe4/R/src-sqlite.r) has some support for `VIEW`s (take a look at the source for `db_list_tables.SQLiteConnection`). Perhaps file an issue for a feature request for PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 5):

David, Greg, thank's for Your feed backs.

I actually found a solution for my problem, I can make dplyr read a VIEW by 
using the `build_sql` function in dplyr to make a "SQL tunnel" directly into PostgreSQL.

Lets say nicStats6 is a TABLE in PostgreSQL, then I can "import" it into dplyr with

```
My_nicStats6 <- tbl(centralstats, "nicStats6")
```

As written in my original question this wont work for a VIEW, so when nicStats5 is a VIEW in PostgreSQL

```
My_nicStats5 <-tbl(centralstats, "nicStats5")
```

will result in error "table not found"

However this "SQL tunnel" to nicStats5 works:

```
My_nicStats5 <- tbl(centralstats, build_sql('SELECT * FROM "nicStats5"'))
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know anything about R. I looked through the dplyr code and see a dependency on a function called  dbListTables.  Looking at the source in RPostgreSQL for PostgreSQL.R:

```
## convenience methods
setMethod("dbListTables", "PostgreSQLConnection",
      def = function(conn, ...){
          out <- dbGetQuery(conn,
                            paste("select tablename from pg_tables where schemaname !='information_schema'",
                                  "and schemaname !='pg_catalog'", ...))
          if (is.null(out) || nrow(out) == 0)
              out <- character(0)
          else
              out <- out[, 1]
          out
      },
      valueClass = "character"
      )
```

This function seems to be referenced here, in the dply code:

```
# Doesn't return TRUE for temporary tables
#' @export
db_has_table.PostgreSQLConnection <- function(con, table, ...) {
  table %in% db_list_tables(con)
}
```

There is also another low level function dbExistTable, which is also based on the pg_tables view.

so, the answer to your question is no, dply does not support postgres views.

but, some minor changes to the dply code might yield what you need.

-g

Answer (score 0):

You can pull data from a view. Instead of passing the table name, pass a sql command to select all from the view. This is the same as creating a table from arbitrary sql as described in the [dplyr vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html).

Table:

```
 nicStats5 <-tbl(centralstats, "nicStats5")
```

View:

```
 nicStats5 <- tbl(centralstats, sql("select * from nicStats5"))
```

NOTE: `build_sql` will work here but that function is designed to be used for escaping expressions in the input.

```
x <- "nicStats5"
build_sql("SELECT * FROM ", x)
```